# Como fazer Bootstrap funcionar no IE7

Tags: html5, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

existe alguma forma de tornar o `Bootstrap` compatível com `IE`,
na documentação fala sobre o **Respond.js** mas não funcionou,
segue [link de exemplo](http://www.agttvtatuape.com.br/bootstrap/)

```
<!doctype html>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://djyhxgczejc94.cloudfront.net/frameworks/bootstrap/3.0.0/themes/white-plum/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css">
```

</script>



  </script>
  </script>

- col-md-4 - 
            
            
                 - col-md-4 - 
            
            
                 - col-md-4 -

```
    <div class="row">   
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="well"> - col-md-6 - </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="well"> - col-md-6 - </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

isto se comporta assim no **chrome**:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
e assim no **IE7**:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: de qual versão do IE você está falando?

Comment: testei no `IE7` e `IE8`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O Bootstrap da suporte para Internet explorer 8 +

> Internet Explorer 8 and 9 are also supported, however, please be aware
>   that some CSS3 properties and HTML5 elements are not fully supported
>   by these browsers. In addition, Internet Explorer 8 requires the use
>   of Respond.js to enable media query support.

Algumas features não são suportadas, como "border-radius"...etc (Se tiver dúvidas do que pode ou não pode utilizar ..e onde: http://caniuse.com/)

O template "básico" do Bootstrap é: (http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: só para ilustrar a escolha deles, http://theie7countdown.com/

Comment: kkkk, particularmente eu concordo,    mas preciso fazer funcionar no IE7 e IE8

Answer (score 0):

Tive um problema uma tempo atrás com o Bootstrap e o IE. Que foi resolvido da seguinte maneira:

```
<!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Colocando isso dentro do  resolveu o meu problema. Ele acabava perdendo as colunas e algumas configurações como por exemplo Tags de HTML5.